# reduceByKey in spark python with tuple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD of `(key, (val1,val2))`. For this `rdd`, I would like to apply `reduceByKey` function and my requirement is to find minimum of `val2` against a single key and also extract the `val1` of the resulted minimum `val2`.
Eg: `(1,(a,4)),(2,(b,3)),(1,(c,2)),(2,(d,1))`
In this I wanted the result set as `(1,(c,2)),(2,(d,1))`

I have in my mind below python code, but here I am getting the first `val1`, not the `val1` corresponding to minimum `val2`.

```
rdd2 = rdd1.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1],x[3])))
rdd3 = rdd2.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:(x[0],min(x[1],y[1])))
```

Please help me to modify the code inorder to get my required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed was `if else` in the `reduceByKey` function as

```
rdd3 = rdd2.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x if(x[1] < y[1]) else y)
```

which should give you your desired output as

```
#(1, ('c', 2))
#(2, ('d', 1))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use `min` with `key` argument:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter

rdd.reduceByKey(partial(min, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, i am going to get the required result by using scala, since i have now learnt scala bit more, I can now answer my own question as below:

```
val list = List((1,('a',4)),(2,('b',3)),(1,('c',2)),(2,('d',1)))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(list)
rdd.reduceByKey((rec1,rec2) => if(rec1._2 > rec2._2) rec2 else rec1).foreach(println)
```

> Output:
>
> (2,(d,1))
>
> (1,(c,2))

I have mentioned this code here, because others can refer and find it useful.
Thank you...